SELinux denying DB connections despite being enabled
I need help with SELinux, it will not allow database connections despite being enabled.
I know that SELinux is the issue as turning it off eliminates the connection error I receive: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied.
I also realize the security issues of turning it off.
I have searched as many solutions as possible. They all seem to give the same solution as this thread:
How do I allow MySQL connections through SELinux?
Running the commands in this thread I get the following output
sestatus:

SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      33

getsebool -a | grep httpd:

httpd_can_network_connect --> on
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on

My System Setup is as follows:

CentOS 9 Stream x64
Apache 2.4.57
MariaDB 10.11.8
PHP 8.1.29 (php-fpm)

What am I missing here?

Please don't post links to images of text. Include the output of those commands in your question, as plain text.

Hello, can you edit your question to add the output of audit2allow -a please?
